# Mantain long Transaction Session in Spring3 and Hibernate4

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, transactions

I get **LazyInitializationException** to Shop.events Collection in below scenario.

I know problem might transaction session is closed before call shop.getEvents is executed.

I was learning about OpenSessionInViewFilter, but i think is no good idea mantain every transaction sessions in every calls life to the server. And FetchType.EAGER is not good neither.

I need help to solve this question. Thank you in advance.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop")
public class Shop implements Serializable {

    // Another class attributes.    

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Event> events;

    // Getters and setters.

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event implements Serializable {

    // Another class attributes.

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id", nullable = false)
    private Shop shop;

    // Getters and setters.

}
```

Persistence layer implementation.

```
public interface AbstractDao<E, I extends Serializable> {

    E findUniqueByCriteria(Criteria criteria);

}
```

---

```
public interface ShopDao extends AbstractDao<Shop, String>{

    Shop getShopFromId(int shop_id, int manager_id);

}
```

---

```
@Repository("shopDao")
public class ShopDaoImpl extends AbstractDaoImpl<Shop, String> implements ShopDao {

    protected ShopDaoImpl() {

        super(Shop.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Shop getShopFromId(int shop_id, int manager_id) {

        Criteria criteria = this.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Shop.class)
                .add(Restrictions.and(
                Restrictions.like("active", true),
                Restrictions.like("id", shop_id)))
                .createCriteria("manager").add(
                Restrictions.like("id", manager_id));

        return (Shop) this.findUniqueByCriteria(criteria);
    }

}
```

---

```
public interface ShopService {

    Shop getShopFromId(int shop_id, int manager_id);

}
```

---

```
@Service("shopService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class ShopServiceImpl implements ShopService {

    @Autowired
    private ShopDao shopDao;

    @Override
    public Shop getShopFromId(int shop_id, int manager_id) {

        return this.shopDao.getShopFromId(shop_id, manager_id);
    }

}
```

---

Controller look like this.

Class attributes.

```
@Autowired
private ShopService shopService;
```

Method Controller.

```
Manager manager = (Manager) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("manager");

Shop shop = (Shop) this.shopService.getShopFromId(shop_id, manager.getId());

Set<Event> events = shop.getEvents();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is configure Controller method with @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED). Thereby is use same transaction session in method persistence operations.